# Recursive new Promise: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, callstack, botkit

I'm getting a RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

```
function getUser(userId) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      controller.storage.users.get(userId, function(err, user) {
        if (err) reject(err);

        if (user) {
          if(!(user.orderData.pendingItem)) {
            getUser(userId)
          }
          else {
            resolve(user.orderData.pendingItem);
          }
        }
      })
    })
  };
```

The dilemma I'm having is that whenever I run `controller.storage.users.get` it does not always resolve all of the properties and values of the user object right away, which is why I attempt to run it again if `orderData.pendingItem` is not there.

However, I guess because it gets run so many times it's giving me a call stack error.

What's the best way to approach this or resolve this issue?

Comment: This looks like a phone being used as a hammer. Surely the better solution would be to wait for whatever is setting `user.orderData.pendingItem` to finish instead. At the least, add some kind of delay to this.

Comment: Even if you get this to work, you have essentially made a `while(true)` but recursive. It would be better to make `pendingItem` a promise wherever its being populated, then in your code you can resolve it. That way your not creating a call stack while its waiting to be complete.

Comment: @ug_ I agree with your comment. However my problem at the moment is that all the data is being stored in memory, while `user` or `orderData` should actually be stored in a DB so that I can place a promise on the query instead. However, I'm pretty much stuck untilI get the approval to move forward with a DB.

Answer (score 4):

Ideally, you should be listening for some event rather than polling, but on the understanding that this is a temporary workaround ...

`new Promise()` runs its constructor synchronously and it would appear that `controller.storage.users.get()` also runs its callback synchronously. The possibility of "Maximum call stack size exceeded" can be avoided by forcing the recursive `getUser()` call to be made *asynchronously* and the simplest way to do that is to chain `new Promise().then(/* recurse from here */)`.

```
function getUser(userId) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        controller.storage.users.get(userId, function(err, user) {
            if (err) reject(err);
            if (!user) reject(new Error('no user for id: ' + useId)); // this branch needs to be catered for
            resolve(user); // make `user` available to the .then() below
        });
    }).then(function(user) {
        return (user.orderData && user.orderData.pendingItem) || getUser(userId); // compact and safe
    });
}
```

That should do the job but without the "Maximum call stack size" safeguard, stands a good chance of frying a processor or two for no good reason.

As suggested in the comments above, you can and probably should add some delay into the recursion :

```
function delay(t) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        setTimeout(resolve, t);
    });
}

function getUser(userId) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        controller.storage.users.get(userId, function(err, user) {
            if (err) reject(err);
            if (!user) reject(new Error('no user for id: ' + useId)); // this branch needs to be catered for
            resolve(user); // make `user` available to the .then() below
        });
    }).then(function(user) {
        return (user.orderData && user.orderData.pendingItem) || delay(200).then(function() { // adjust the delay to maximum acceptable value
            return getUser(userId);
        });
    });
}
```